# sign in with apple not working only in ios 14.5 webview

Tags: ios, authentication, webview

i developed sign in with apple with js.

so it works fine on other platforms except ios 14.5 webview.

even it works fine on simulator and ios mobile safarai

only not working in ios 14.5 webview

if i tapped sign in with apple button, system log printed like that

[SOAuthorizationCore] canceling now - no SPI authorization delegate.

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you found a reason ? restarting the device helps for a while

Comment: um,, i guess it is a bug.
i didn't edit my code, but it works fine.
if you have same error,
Turn off and on your device.
if not, remove your app and install again